# google api token expired or revoked?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, discord, credentials, google-authentication

I have set up a discord bot a week ago that uses google drive api. The bot worked for a week in a web hosting server, and today I checked and it's been giving me this error every time i started up the bot.

```
client_secret.json-drive-v3-(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'],)
['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Unknown1\Documents\discordbot\bot.py", line 5, in <module>
    from googledrive import find_recent
  File "C:\Users\Unknown1\Documents\discordbot\googledrive.py", line 10, in <module>
    service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)
  File "C:\Users\Unknown1\Documents\discordbot\Google.py", line 28, in Create_Service
    cred.refresh(Request())
  File "C:\Users\Unknown1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\credentials.py", line 200, in refresh
    access_token, refresh_token, expiry, grant_response = _client.refresh_grant(
  File "C:\Users\Unknown1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\_client.py", line 248, in refresh_grant
    response_data = _token_endpoint_request(request, token_uri, body)
  File "C:\Users\Unknown1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\_client.py", line 124, in _token_endpoint_request
    _handle_error_response(response_body)
  File "C:\Users\Unknown1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\_client.py", line 60, in _handle_error_response
    raise exceptions.RefreshError(error_details, response_body)
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Token has been expired or revoked.', '{\n  "error": "invalid_grant",\n  "error_description": "Token has been expired or revoked."\n}')
PS C:\Users\Unknown1\Documents\discordbot>
```

I checked the client_secret_file.json and redownloaded it from google cloud api credentials and its still the same thing. I'm not sure where to go about from here to fix this issue.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
API_NAME = 'drive'
API_VERSION = 'v3'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)

#in the google drive web link, there will be a folder id.

folder_id = '1ANm4frKaL_JeMEewRMDBLWiiY3Srh-B-'

query = f"parents = '{folder_id}'"

response = service.files().list(q=query).execute()
files = response.get('files')
nextPageToken = response.get('nextPageToken')

while nextPageToken:
    response = service.files().list(q=query,pageToken=nextPageToken).execute()
    files.extend(response.get('files'))
    nextpageToken = response.get('nextPageToken')

df = pd.DataFrame(files)
```

I have set up a new project , OAuth 2.0 Client ID Credentials, following this youtube video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FAM_4J7ywcE&ab_channel=nouthemes

and deleted the old one in hopes of replacing the client secret file with the new one. Now I am getting a new error :

```
client_secret.json-drive-v3-(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'],)
['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Unknown1\Documents\discordbot\bot.py", line 5, in <module>
    from googledrive import find_recent
  File "C:\Users\Unknown1\Documents\discordbot\googledrive.py", line 10, in <module>
    service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)
  File "C:\Users\Unknown1\Documents\discordbot\Google.py", line 28, in Create_Service
    cred.refresh(Request())
  File "C:\Users\Unknown1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\credentials.py", line 200, in refresh
    access_token, refresh_token, expiry, grant_response = _client.refresh_grant(
  File "C:\Users\Unknown1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\_client.py", line 248, in refresh_grant
    response_data = _token_endpoint_request(request, token_uri, body)
  File "C:\Users\Unknown1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\_client.py", line 124, in _token_endpoint_request
    _handle_error_response(response_body)
  File "C:\Users\Unknown1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\_client.py", line 60, in _handle_error_response
    raise exceptions.RefreshError(error_details, response_body)
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('deleted_client: The OAuth client was deleted.', '{\n  "error": "deleted_client",\n  "error_description": "The OAuth client was deleted."\n}')
```

I'm stuck.

Comment: You would better pose your code as well, how you authenticate. Anyway, you should get a new token if expires. Or, you should refresh before it expires for security.

Comment: I wasn't really sure how to get a new token from google, so I created a new project, OAuth 2.0 Client ID, and OAuth consent screen in hopes of replacing the old client secret file for my code. I have attached my code at the bottom.

Comment: Is `Create_Service` is a function you defined? Show me what you did with `google.auth.*`.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the token as it is done on the [Quickstart[(https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample)?